# ListView customize first/last cell

Tags: listview, javafx

I was searching for a solution how to change first and last cell differently then the other cells. I know css for odd/even cells etc but didn't find a solution for change first/last cell. Target: having the first and the last cell background radius while the rest does not. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Solution, extend cell-factory while checking index of row:

```
  list.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Object>, ListCell<Object>>() {
  ...    
     super.updateItem(object, empty);

     if(!empty) {
        super.setGraphic(new Label(paramT));
        // Styling the first and last cells.
       if(getIndex() == 0 || getIndex() == (getListView().getItems().size()-1)) {
          this.getStyleClass().add("your-style");
       }
  ...
```